# Using jsdom in chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: browserify, jsdom, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In chrome extensions manifest v3 it's stated that background.js is now replaced with service worker and dom is not available in a service worker. Then suggests `undom` or `jsdom` to be used as an alternative for DOMParser API.

> Libraries such as jsdom can be used to emulate a typical browser
> window environment, complete with DOMParser, event propagation, and
> other capabilities like requestAnimationFrame. Lighter-weight
> alternatives like undom provide just enough DOM to power many frontend
> frameworks and libraries.

But `undom` is too limited and is just capable of creating elements but not querying dom elements which I need despite being easily usable in the service worker. So it tried to use `jsdom` which is more thorough with a drawback of a ~6MB size.

I tried to import `jsdom` and I learned it can be done using `browserify` in a comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70175127/1306720) question when I use a `browserify`ed bundle in a simple HTML file it works as expected but not in the chrome extension, which gives this error:

`ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66408379/1306720) answer to load the required js files like this:

```
try {
  importScripts('assets/jsdom.bundle.js', 'common.js', 'search.js', 'background.js');
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

and tried to use it like this in `search.js`:

```
const jsdom = require("./assets/jsdom.bundle");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
```

How `jsdom` can be used in a chrome extension service worker correctly?

Comment: Run `browserify --standalone` so that the library will set a global variable `JSDOM` or `jsdom` (test it).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your reply I tried that and I think I have gone a step ahead but it seems with `--standalone`, I need to change my usage of JSDOM do but I can't find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm's comment that put me in the right direction I managed to make it work like this:

1- Created a js file named main.js:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
exports.jsdom = jsdom;
```

2- browserified it with this command:

`browserify main.js -o jsdom.bundle.js --standalone jsdomModule`

3- And finally used it in the service worker like this:

```
const { JSDOM } = jsdomModule.jsdom;
const jd = new JSDOM('<div>hello</div>');
```

Then I got this error when calling `querySelector` function:

`EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".`

So after my 4th weekend on this, I gave up on using jsdom and went for doing the job in the content script and using "Message passing" to communicate with service worker which worked like a charm.
I think google guys should remove their jsdom suggestion from the documentation.

Comment: I use https://github.com/WebReflection/linkedom with service worker.